# Conditional Formatting - Comparing Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have some data I would like to add some conditional formatting to. The data set is below:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2r8Q0.png)

On the Dataset below, Row 19, the MS 'Maximum' will always be 50, the US column is 'Used' and AS is 'Available'. Each day the US and AS columns should change values (as seen in Row 19).

Question:
I want to create some conditional formatting which will calculate the AS 'Available' as a percentage of MS 'Maximum'.

Example:
Row 19 - MS=50, AS=7 (Calculate 7 as a % of 50)

Values:

```
AS <= 70% - 100% Green,
AS <= 20% - 69% - Yellow,
AS <= 0% - 19% - Red
```

The conditional format needs to cover ALL AS as a % of MS data in the dataset (any cell with a number value) and NOT a specific cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select the columns that you have to conditional format
- Click conditional formatting --> new rule
- Select "use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- In the formula area paste the below formula,

Formula:

```
=AND((((A2-B2)/A2)*100)>=0,(((A2-B2)/A2)*100)<=19)
```

Where,

```
A2 is MS, B2 is US
```

- Select a formatting color (should be red) of your choice and click ok

Now do the same for other two formulae,

```
=AND((((A2-B2)/A2)*100)>=20,(((A2-B2)/A2)*100)<=69)
=AND((((A2-B2)/A2)*100)>=70,(((A2-B2)/A2)*100)<=100)
```

While doing this, you need to select colors yellow and green respectively. Let me know if you need anything

Comment: Am glad that it worked. Please upvote and mark as correct answer